# SQL Server Try Catch Transastion

Tags: sql-server, transaction, error-handling

I need to know if the T-SQL below is correct to roll back if something bad happens.

I first create a temp table

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#LocalSummary') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP TABLE #LocalSummary   

CREATE TABLE  #LocalSummary (
```

then I populate the table

```
INSERT INTO #LocalSummary
   SELECT *....
```

Then I start my try catch

```
BEGIN TRY
 BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    DELETE FROM LocalSummaryRealTable

    INSERT INTO LocalSummaryRealTable
        SELECT S.*
        FROM #LocalSummary AS S 

    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
       IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
              ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
    ...
```

I noticed when I did the insert into the `LocalSummaryRealTable` the columns didn't line up and I got an error. I expected things to roll back but in SSMS query window it gave me a message that the trans wasn't committed and asked me if I wanted to commit it. Why would this ask me when it should of been rolled back?

Comment: This resource, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx, in example B, shows the transaction starting before the try catch block. In other words, move the Begin Transaction above the Begin Try line.

Comment: if moving it up do i have to put IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
    COMMIT TRANSACTION; after end try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` prior to the `BEGIN TRY`:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
BEGIN TRY
    DELETE FROM dbo.LocalSummeryRealTable;
    INSERT INTO dbo.LocalSummeryRealTable
    SELECT S.*
    FROM  #LocalSummery' AS S;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
       IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; 
END CATCH
```

Also, please schema-qualify references to database objects such as tables, views, stored procedures etc.  Also, you should get in the habit of adding semi-colons to the end of each statement.

`SET XACT_ABORT ON;` is [not necessary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx) if you are explicitly rolling back the transaction inside the `CATCH` block.

Comment: thanks ,i'll try it out.  do i need SET XACT_ABORT ON ? not real sure if this is another way to roll back or I need to do both

Comment: I added that detail to my answer